How to programmatically toggle scene understanding (Occlusion mesh) in VisionOS
On vision os we can go to Visualizations > Occlusion Mesh

To show something like the below:

I would like to be able to toggle that in the code, like a function I can toggle, or just add it. I was checking Visualizing and Interacting with a Reconstructed Scene from apple. The example they using is using
@IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
Then
func toggleMeshButtonPressed(_ button: UIButton) {
        let isShowingMesh = arView.debugOptions.contains(.showSceneUnderstanding)
        if isShowingMesh {
            arView.debugOptions.remove(.showSceneUnderstanding)
            button.setTitle("Show Mesh", for: [])
        } else {
            arView.debugOptions.insert(.showSceneUnderstanding)
            button.setTitle("Hide Mesh", for: [])
        }
}

When I try that in visionOS it gives me an error : 'ARView' is unavailable in visionOS
I am able to reconstruct the scene using :
import ARKit
import RealityKit
import RealityKitContent
import SwiftData
import SwiftUI

@Observable
class EntityModel {
    let session = ARKitSession()
    let sceneReconstruction = SceneReconstructionProvider()
    var contentEntity = Entity()

This is also a copy paste from some of the apples code
    func processReconstructionUpdates() async {
        for await update in sceneReconstruction.anchorUpdates {
            let meshAnchor = update.anchor
            
            guard let shape = try? await ShapeResource.generateStaticMesh(from: meshAnchor) else { continue }
            switch update.event {
                case .added:
                    let entity = ModelEntity()
                    entity.transform = Transform(matrix: meshAnchor.originFromAnchorTransform)
                    entity.collision = CollisionComponent(shapes: [shape], isStatic: true)
                    entity.components.set(InputTargetComponent())
                    
                    entity.physicsBody = PhysicsBodyComponent(mode: .static)
                    
                    meshEntities[meshAnchor.id] = entity
                    contentEntity.addChild(entity)
                case .updated:
                    guard let entity = meshEntities[meshAnchor.id] else { continue }
                    entity.transform = Transform(matrix: meshAnchor.originFromAnchorTransform)
                    entity.collision?.shapes = [shape]
                case .removed:
                    meshEntities[meshAnchor.id]?.removeFromParent()
                    meshEntities.removeValue(forKey: meshAnchor.id)
            }
        }
    }

How can I add/toggle the Occlusion Mesh on the visionOS properly?
